# Laravel Test Cases

Tags: testcase

I am using Laravel 5.3 and for testing purpose, I have created a folder called "Helpers" is "app" folder. In "Helpers" folder, there is a file named credentials.php where I will declare some strings then I will use it later. Credentials.php looks like
`

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class Credential
{

}
`
```

In the 'tests' folder there is folder called 'links' and in this folder there is file called something.php and it looks like

```
<?php

use App\Helpers\Credential;

class something extends TestCase
{
}
```

and its working correctly...Problem arising when I am trying to put the "helpers" folder from "app" to "tests" folder. I dont want to put the "Helper" folder in "app" directory. I have changed namespace and other things, nothing works. I am new to laravel and seeking your help and suggestion.

Comment: Where you have created the "tests" folder.

Comment: its the default laravel tests folder. I just want to bring my "helpers" folder into default " tests " folder

Answer (score 0):

Update Composer.json and add files key in autoload section.

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "tests/helpers.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

After Adding this, run the following command.

```
composer dump-autoload
```